# Risk of taking another job

Tags: software-industry, career-development, software-development, careers

I am curious how do people make decision in such situations.

Say I am Software developer (Front end), with say 4 years of experience roughly.
Now, on my current job, I handle all the tasks well.
Pay maybe not best, but ok.
Now, when I get another offer, I am always hesitant because of following
thing.
I am not confident, how I will manage the tasks in new company: what kind of tasks will I get, what will be the complexity etc?

To get into more specific details, say I am more Javascript oriented Front end developer, less skilled in CSS - so I am concerned about getting advanced CSS tasks.

So in general how do people solve such problem? To defeat fear of changing job to another company in a situation like mine?

How to reduce such risks or make sure I will get tasks relevant to my skillset?

Comment: I think it's important to remember that getting tasks in which you are not experienced is an excellent opportunity to learn something new.

Comment: OP here(forgot to follow registration): why downvotes? Can someone tell, so that I can improve in the future?

Answer (score 5):

Being able to pick up new skills is an important talent for a developer. It's unlikely that you'll be using exactly the same technology if you stay in a job more than a year or two. If you have become proficient in some technologies, then you should be able to learn others and apply the skills and methodologies you've learnt to new languages or frameworks.

Things to ask at interviews would include not only about the specific technology you're using now, but also about the company's policy towards training and development. Lots of companies might be more committed when interviewing than when you come to request time to do a course/conference/training, but if they're not willing to talk about providing training in an interview that's a red flag.

In the workplace, you need to learn how to discuss your skills with management and team leaders, to admit when something is outside your expertise, and to request help from colleagues. A good manager will have some idea of your skills but may assign you tasks outside your comfort zone to encourage you to learn and develop. You also need to know how to manage your career development and training needs as you progress: both when you start and later in annual appraisals or as needed.

Finally, it seems you may have confidence issues. Remember, if you're honest at the interview, then you will be hired because the company believes you can do the job. You should remember that. If you have good, supportive managers that have faith in you, then that makes it a lot easier, and that's another thing you should pay attention to at the interview.

Answer (score 4):

The key is honesty in the interview and asking questions.  There is also a skill to interpreting the answers.

Simple questions like:  How much CSS is involved in this job? or What are you looking for in a developer?  Will give you an idea of what is involved.  Getting answers from the tech lead is always the best here, as some light CSS work could be interpreted as advanced by management.

However, needs do change for an employer.  For example, they may not have much javascript work in the future, but may need a bunch of CSS and C++ people.  You can either learn those skills or move on.  Moving on is normal and expected in Software development.